# Use media content types on a publishing page

Tags: 2010, content-type, publishing-page

I'm trying to make a new publishing page that can use either Images, Video or Audio.

I'we already made one that uses the PublishingWebControls:RichImageField but cant find equivalents for video and audio.

I would be fine with havíng 3 fields on one page that the user can choose either of the 3.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: Hello Oddmar i'm facing same issue i tried to using webpart as well as custom field but not success can u show me how u solved this

Comment: Hello Rakesh.

Unfortunately i do not have access to that source code any more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've handled this before is if they need to link to content, like on youtube, give them a hyperlink filed to do so.  If they want to upload video or audio, then put a web part zone in the page layout so they can drop in a media web part.

Answer (score 1):

As Eric said, one way is to add the link field or web part zone.

But, you can also integrate the multimedia content on publishing pages via

1. A media web part absed on Silver light 3.0
2. A media field and media field control
3. The Content Query web part
4. Javascript API to manipulate the media player

Comment: Hello Falak i had used PublishingPageImage Column in custom pagelayout it is working fine now i want to use same for video where user can add video like publishing page image field so is it possible to do that...